# sql not populating off php

Tags: php, mysql

Just getting back into this after a few years. So I have a form that populates sql db. Problem is that it's not populating and I can't see why. It connects to db no issues, on post it shows that it works but in the db nothing is populating.

form.php that main form

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
// Include config file
require_once 'bug_report_config.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$bug_report_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // Check if add-on name is empty
    if (empty(trim($_POST['bug_report']))) {
        $bug_report_err = 'Please enter bug description.';
    }

    // Validate information
    if (empty($bug_report_err)) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO crew_report (description, resolved, submitted, ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        $bug_report = trim($_POST["bug_report"]);
        $resolved = '0';
        $submitted = strtotime("now");
        //grab ip
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            //ip from share internet
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            //ip pass from proxy
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '/' . $ip;

        $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $bug_report, $resolved, $submitted, $ip);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        echo "Records inserted successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql." . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    $link->close();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bug Reporting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font: 14px sans-serif;
        }

        .wrapper {
            width: 350px;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Bug Reporting</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your bug report.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($bug_report_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Bug Details</label>
                <input type="bug_report" name="bug_report" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $bug_report_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

config.php connecting to db

```
config.<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'blah');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'blah');
define('DB_NAME', 'blahh');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect to database. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    echo 'Connected to db<br>';
}
?>
```

Thank you for your help. I am trying to get back into this and there is something small that I have a feeling I am forgetting or over-looking.

Comment: You should have error checking when you perform the `INSERT` query.

Comment: Your error message that says "Could not prepare query" is in the `else` block for `if (empty($bug_report_err))`, it has nothing to do with the query.

Comment: I see that, made the change but still nothing and shows all good.

<code>
    // Validate bullshit
    if (empty($bug_report_err)) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO crew_report (description, resolved, submitted, ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        echo "Records inserted successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql." . mysqli_error($link);
    }
</code>

Comment: That code never executes the query.

Comment: And the `else` statement is still attached to testing `$bug_report_err`, not the query.

Comment: `$stmt = $link->prepare($sql) or die ($link->error);` and `$stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);`