# I'm using PHP to insert data into mysql DB and all the data shows blank and gives me no errors

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP to insert data into MySQL DB and all the data shows blank and gives no errors. I'm new to coding and trying to teach myself the basics.

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$user_name = $user_email = $user_password = $confirm_user_password = "";
$user_name_err = $user_email_err = $user_password_err = $confirm_user_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["user_name"]))){
        $user_name_err = "Please enter a user name";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_name = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_user_name);

            // Set parameters
            $param_user_name = trim($_POST["user_name"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $user_name_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $user_name = trim($_POST["user_name"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }


     // Validate email
    if(empty(trim($_POST["user_email"]))){
        $user_email_err = "Please enter a email.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_email = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_user_email);

            // Set parameters
            $param_user_email = trim($_POST["user_email"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $user_email_err = "This useremail is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $user_email = trim($_POST["user_email"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["user_password"]))){
        $user_password_err = "Please enter a password";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["user_password"])) < 6){
        $user_password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $user_password = trim($_POST["user_password"]);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_user_password"]))){
        $confirm_user_password_err = "Please confirm user password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_user_password = trim($_POST["confirm_user_password"]);
        if(empty($user_password_err) && ($user_password != $confirm_user_password)){
            $confirm_user_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($user_name_err) && empty($user_password_err) && empty($user_email_err) && empty($confirm_user_password_err)){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_email, user_password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_user_name, $param_user_password, $param_user_email);

            // Set parameters
            $param_user_name = $user_name;
            $param_user_password = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            $param_user_email = $user_email;
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: logInPage.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: "I can not post this question because my post is mostly code"  That should be a signal to you that you need to write more text describing your problem in detail, including what debugging you have already done to try to narrow down the source of the issue.

Comment: debug your code line by line, so you will come to know where is the error.

Comment: ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Have you taken a gander at the server's error logs?

Comment: @PatrickQ yep - I see it now. Edited my comment.

Comment: Is this homework, swear I have seen this code somewhere else today already

Comment: You're only posting an error if execute fails. It could be bailing somewhere else in the code

Comment: @RiggsFolly  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59571634/sql-not-populating-off-php) has some similar code, but doesn't appear exactly the same.

Comment: @PatrickQ Hmm that makes 3 then, as I dont remember that one :)

Comment: " I can not post pictures on this site yet"...that's fine, we prefer actual tables of data as text, rather than as a picture. That way the data is actually usable and searchable. Taking a picture of something which is actually text is pointless when you can just paste the original text.

Comment: You could decomplicate this code by doing one query like this `"SELECT COUNT(id) as xx FROM users WHERE user_name = ? or user_email = ?"` then just fetch the count, if its > 0 you already got a name or email registerd.

Comment: All these error parameters like `$confirm_user_password_err` etc...you never echo them. So if one of those parameters is populated, your code will never run the insert code. But also it will not output any error message either (at least not according to the code snippet you've provided). So in that case it would probably appear to do nothing. You need some extra code to show these errors on screen. Also, you need to learn to do some basic debugging - e.g. add some logging or var_dump commands so you can see what path your code is taking when it runs - that'll help you find where problems occur

Comment: @TroyShortt  That error (which you've now removed??) indicates that one of your prepares (whichever one comes before line 76) failed.

Comment: So you went ahead and posted an image of your data anyway, despite the earlier comment? [Bangs head against wall...]